# Creating SOAP Headers in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, soapheader

I'm inexperienced with Web Services and I'm trying my best to get this working based on readings on MSDN and here in stackoverflow. Obviously, I'm still not getting it since I still cannot get it working so I'm seeking help.

Here's what I've been doing and what I need to do:

I have a sample request and a proxy class and with these I need to send a request to a WS using C#

```
    <soap:Header>
    <AppDetails xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.example.com/websvc">
      <AppName>Application1</AppName>
    </AppDetails>
    <userDetails xmlns='http://schemas.example.com/mysoap'>
      <USER xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns='http://schemas.example.com/user_schema'>
        <userid>12345</userid>
        <cid>100</cid>
      </USER>
    </userDetails>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <myRequest_getReport xmlns="http://schemas.example.com/websvc" docID="9999"/>
  </soap:Body>
```

I've been having great success in creating the request via Fiddler because it's straighforward and I just need to fill in the values but I've been struggling for a week now in getting this to work in my code.

Here's the proxy class code:

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.example.com/mysoap")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.example.com/mysoap", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class userDetails : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader
    {

        private System.Xml.XmlElement any_u;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
        public System.Xml.XmlElement Any
        {
            get
            {
                return this.any_u;
            }
            set
            {
                this.any_u = value;
            }
        }
    }


    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.example.com/infrastructure/user_schema")]
    public partial class USER
    {

        private uint userid_u;

        private uint cid_u;

        /// <remarks/>
        public uint userid
        {
            get
            {
                return this.userid_u;
            }
            set
            {
                this.userid_u = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public uint cid
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cid_u;
            }
            set
            {
                this.cid_u = value;
            }
        }
    }



    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.example.com/websvc")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.example.com/websvc", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class AppDetails : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader
    {

        private string appName_u;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string AppName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.appName_u;
            }
            set
            {
                this.appName_u = value;
            }
        }


    }
```

And here's my code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            myRequest req_server = new myRequest("myremoteserver", null); //connects to the server

            // User
            XmlElement UserIdentity = UserDetailsHeader();

            req_server.userIdentityValue = new userDetails();
            req_server.userIdentityValue.Any = UserIdentity;

            // Application
            //XmlElement appDataVal = AppDataHeader();
            req_server.AppDataValue = new AppDetails();
            req_server.AppDataValue.AppName = "Application1";

            // Construct the request
            myRequest_getReport docRequest = new myRequest_getReport();

        }

        private static XmlElement UserDetailsHeader()
        {
            USER myUser = new USER();
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(USER));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(1024);

            myUser.userid = 12345;
            myUser.cid = 100;
            xs.Serialize(ms, myUser);
            ms.Position = 0;
            XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
            xd.Load(ms);

            return xd.DocumentElement;
        }


        private static XmlElement AppDataHeader()
        {
            AppDetails myApp = new AppDetails();
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppDetails));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(1024);

            myApp.AppName = "Application1";
            xs.Serialize(ms, myApp);
            ms.Position = 0;

            XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
            xd.Load(ms);
            return xd.DocumentElement;
        }
```

As you can see in UserDetailsHeader(), I was able to set the values for userid and cid in USER. I also created AppDataHeader() but wasn't able to use it later since I later figure out I didn't have to but I included it here anyway in case there is a need.

I set the UserDetailsHeader() in main() as UserIdentity but when I execute the code, an exception is displayed saying "UserDetails is not defined." Obviously I'm missing something very important here and I want to know what it is.

Could you please point me to the right direction? I am very confused right now and I'm not even sure if my code makes sense. The code in UserDetailsHeader is based on my readings on how to create a SOAP header request in C#, I got this from an MSDN article which I cannot find right now.